# Nonlinear optimization with a solver

Tags: forecasting

I am building a non linear python (or r) program that calculates the # of errors in a model and adjusts the betas and indexes accordingly.

My model is based on this:

```
Sales  |   CMA  |  EstCMA  |   Index   |  Forecast
```

The formula for EstCMA is CMA * Beta1 + Beta1.

The formula for Forecast is EstCMA * Index.

To compute this I am using a pandas dataframe.

However, I need to adjust my model to minimize the errors (Sales - Forecast).

Does anyone know of any GRG like solvers that can do this in Python or R?  Any examples that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to CV! Are there no error terms in your model? You might want to look into the nls package in R.